# Language switching , when user choose the specific language form option menu. it should hold current local until the user change it again

Tags: java, android

I have an android project which supports multiple locales inside an app, like Hindi, English, Urdu, etc. It works fine when I choose the local manually, but the problem is here when I restart the app it gets default local and also rotating on screen.

I don't want to change the local until it changed manually. 
What should I do in Java class inside the main activity? Do I need to create a new Java class instead?

Here is my code for language configuration inside Main Activity:

```
private  void  setAppLocale (String LocaleCode){
        Resources res=getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            conf.setLocale(new Locale(LocaleCode));
        }else {
            conf.locale = new Locale(LocaleCode.toLowerCase());
        }
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

    }
    private Locale locale = null;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (locale != null) {
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration(newConfig);
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you when you choose the language manually store it in `sharedPreferences` .

And by default , in your `sharedPreferences` it will be your local language.